# Force UIView animateWithDuration completion block to be called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have two animations which are overlapping, which, because of the way I've set my method up, causes the second one not to fire. I have a check like so in the beginning of the method:

```
- (void)animateHidden:(BOOL)hidden duration:(CGFloat)seconds delay:(CGFloat)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options disableUserInteraction:(BOOL)disableUserInteraction {
    if (self.hidden == hidden) {
        return;
    }
```

Then, further down, my animation block looks like so:

```
__weak UIView *weakSelf = self;
[UIView animateWithDuration:seconds delay:delay options:options animations:^{
    weakSelf.alpha = hidden ? 0 : 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Return user interaction to previous state
    if (disableUserInteraction) {
        weakSelf.userInteractionEnabled = userInteractionEnabled;
    }
    weakSelf.hidden = hidden;
}];
```

Two animations are kicked off on the same view, one before a service call and one after. If the service call happens quick enough that the view is still animating, `weakSelf.hidden = hidden;` will never be called, and the second animation will exit out since the `hidden` value wasn't updated in time.

Is there anyway that I could force the completion block on the `animation` block to be called? I need to update my `hidden` property before making the check, but can't find a way to accomplish this.

Calling `[self.layer removeAllAnimations]` doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure what else you might be doing in the methods, but... Would it work for you if - instead of using your `hidden` property / variable, check the `.alpha` value? That would tell you if the animation is finished or not.

Comment: Completion block should be called anyway. What you can do? The simples/quickest way is to make flags and check is completion already happened.

Comment: @DonMag The issue with that is that because when we call this method, the view may have originally been hidden with an `alpha` of 1, so checking for an `alpha` value that corresponds to a `hidden` value doesn't work for all views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CABasicAnimation` instead of `UIView` animation, that will solve the problem more accurately.

You can use it like:

```
CABasicAnimation* opacityZero= [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[opacityZero setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[opacityZero setDuration:duration];
[[self layer] addAnimation:opacityZero forKey:@"opacityZero"];
```

And when your service call ends, you can call `[self.layer removeAllAnimations];`

Similarly, you can make the opacity one and tweak the above method as you like.

You can find more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cabasicanimation).

Answer (score 0):

A `__block` prefixed to `hidden` attribute declaration should help.
Something like, 
 `@property (nonatomic) __block BOOL hidden;`

Comment: Unfortunately this is in an extension, so I can't add any stored properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 10+ take a look at UIViewPropertyAnimator
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator?language=objc

Combined with the UIViewAnimating and UIViewImplicitlyAnimating protocols, this allows modification / interruption / pause / resume / stop / etc of the animations.

Basic example (buttons and view set in IB):

```
- (IBAction)startTapped:(id)sender {

    _myAnimator = [UIViewPropertyAnimator
                   runningPropertyAnimatorWithDuration:3.0
                   delay:0.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                   animations:^{
                       _theRedBox.alpha = _theRedBox.alpha > 0 ? 0 : 1;
                   } completion:^(UIViewAnimatingPosition finalPosition) {
                       // do stuff
                   }];

}

- (IBAction)stopTapped:(id)sender {

    [_myAnimator stopAnimation:NO];
    [_myAnimator finishAnimationAtPosition:UIViewAnimatingPositionEnd];

}
```